# Need to fetch records from one table which is not present in another one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, one table has three columns another one has two columns. I need to fetch records from Table1 which is not present in Table2. For example

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,1,1)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,2,2)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,3,3)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2,1,4)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (C1 INT, C2 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1,2)
```

I need the result as shown below

```
C1 C2 C3
--------
1  3   3
2  1   4
```

Comment: Did you try with Left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT Table1.* 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.C1 = Table2.C1 
    AND Table1.C2 = Table2.C2 
WHERE Table2.C1 IS NULL
    AND Table2.C2 IS NULL
```

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` makes no sense. Based on other parts of the query I corrected it to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (which could also be spelled just `LEFT JOIN`). `==` is not Transact-SQL either, should be `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this -

```
SELECT t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select null from table2 t2
                   where t1.c1=t2.c1
                       and t1.c2=t2.c2);
```